# Selenium how to select first option if page has multiple select box using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have 3 select box's in my page

example :

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
</select> 

<select>
  <option value="cat">Cat</option>
  <option value="dog">Dog</option>
</select> 

<select>
  <option value="1">Banana</option>
  <option value="2">Mango</option>
</select>
```

If there has 5 or 6 select box I will always select 1st option, I am unable to do it using selenium.
I have tried below code

```
selectboxs = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select/option[@value=1]")

for selectbox in selectboxs:
    if selectbox:
    selectbox.click()
```

But no any impact, How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: I think you'd want: value='1'

Comment: So you want to select 'Volvo' option ? if so why are you looping over other options? just use: `selectboxs.click()`

Comment: Update the question with the outerHTML of the `<select>` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very near of the solution !

```
selectboxs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//select/option[1]")
```

See the [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) carefully how they select First input child element of the form element with attribute id set to loginForm.

note : It's elements not element !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to grab all the select tags and click the first tag wrap it in A Select and click the first index.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
selects = Select(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('select'))
for select in selects:
    select.select_by_index(1)
```